# How to reflect Laravel Delete Observer for the Model Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a TaskObserver class which records the activities.

When I try to delete the task using

> ::find()

function, it gets reflected in the Task delete observer.

```
$task = Task::find($id);
$task->delete();
```

When I try to delete collection using

```
$task = Task::find($id);
$subTasks = Task::where('parent_id', $task->id)->delete();
```

It does not reflects the delete observer for any subtasks.

Yes, I searched and found 
[Laravel Event Observer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11777#issuecomment-170388067)
. It tells to use ::find() method so it reflects in the observer.

Do I have to loop through all subtasks and use ::find() method?

```
$subTasksId = Task::where('parent_id', $task->id)->pluck('id');
foreach($subTasksId as $subTaskId){
    $deleteSubTask = Task::find($subTask)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to use delete observer you must be get instance of model and then delete it

```
$subTasks = Task::where('parent_id', $task->id)->get(['id']);
foreach($subTasks as $subTask){
    $deleteSubTask = $subTask->delete();
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the same for the Post model. I deleted all the related child posts and tried to delete parent post. It did not worked. $post = Post::where('uuid', $uuid)->first(); $post->delete(); It did not use delete observer. Can you know why?

Comment: You must be sure `Post::where('uuid', $uuid)->first();`  return `Post` model. It all ok that case `->delete()` method must be call observer

Comment: Yes I am sure it returns the Post model. Only parent post are not storing observer.

Comment: You must be check Observer correctly registered for Post model

Comment: It is set only for child posts and not for parent post.